# Устранение задержки дополнения в программе LyX

Tags: lyx

Вот, когда мы в математическом режиме начинаем писать какую-либо команды, варианты завершения этой команды:

[image]

выпадают не сразу, так что это прилично тормозит работу. Так же и в обычном тексте: когда начинаешь набирать ранее уже набиравшееся слово, варианты их автодополнения вываливаются не сразу - опять-таки тормоз. Хотелось бы научиться это устранять.

Answer (score 0):

А выход в следующем. Нужно в **Инструменты>Настройки...>Редактирование>Дополнения ввода**, там, где *Общие* счетчик *Задержка дополнения (сек.)* установить в ноль, а чтобы дополнения не задерживались и в обычном тексте, нужно обнулить и счетчик *Задержка всплывающего окна (сек.)* или наоборот, я не помню точно, какой счетчик за что отвечает, помню только, что при обнулении этих двух счетчиков дополнения и там, и там начинают выскакивать мгновенно. А вообще при мгновенно выскакивающих дополнениях (и в формулах, и в обычном тексте) то место настроек выглядит у меня так:

[image]